# Can $u\cdot v=-7$ if $||u||=3$ and $||v||=2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am unsure how to begin the problem and I failed to guess a particular solution. 
Could anyone give me some hints, please?

Comment: $u\cdot v$ by definition is $|u|\cdot |v|\cdot \cos\theta$. If we could have $u\cdot v=-7, |u|=3,|v|=2$, then $\cos\theta=\frac{-7}{3\cdot 2}<-1$, contradiction.

Comment: Hmm ... do you have a formula for $u\cdot v$ in terms of $\|u\|$, $\|v\|$ and perhaps something more?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that $u \cdot v = ||u||\ ||v|| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the smaller angle between the vectors. What do we know about $|\cos \theta|$?

Comment: Jeez how can I forget about such a basic formula, but thanks a lot anyway.